# Time Convert- converting minutes into hours

Tags: javascript

Have the function TimeConvert(num) take the num parameter being passed and return the number of hours and minutes the parameter converts to (ie. if num = 63 then the output should be 1:3). Separate the number of hours and minutes with a colon.
Another example if input:126 then output: 2:06.
This is what I did and I do not understand why it is wrong. For an input of 126, it is giving me an output of 11:06.

```
function TimeConvert(num) { 
if(num<60 && num>10){ 
  return 0+":"+num
} 
if(num<10){ 
  return 0+":"+0+num
}

let object={ 
  12:720, 
  11:660,
  10:600,
  9:540,
  8:480,
  7:420,
  6:360,
  5:300,
  4:240,
  3:180,
  2:120,
  1:60
  } 


let time=""


for (let key in object){ 
  while(num>=object[key]){ 
   time += key 
  num-= object[key]
  }
} 
return time+":"+num

}
```

Comment: Why not just divide by 60 and floor the result to get the hours? Then subtract the hours * 60 from the minutes to get the number of minutes remaining.

Comment: This is a problem that can be solved with many ways, but the best one is using better math like what @youdateme mentioned above^^

Comment: @kellys Or he/she could just use the mod operator for the remainder. It's a learning process, and that's why we're all here :)

Comment: The question is asking why his approach is not working. He is not asking how to convert minutes to hours and minutes, nor inviting 'better' ways. He has tried an interesting, if uncoventional, approach and is asking why it is not working. Anyone capable of conceiving this method (which is an entirely valid algorithm) is probably well aware that other ways exist.  As it turns out, a couple of minor type-errors are causing it to fail (corrected in my answer). There is nothing wrong with the approach (which in my view is novel and interesting)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, there are many ways to reduce minutes to hours and minutes. However, to address your question as to why your approach is failing:

Object keys are treated as strings, not numbers. Also, you have declared time as a string.

For your approach to work, you have to make BOTH these changes:

`let time=""` -> `let time = 0`

and

`time += key`  -> `time += parseInt(key)`

Working snippet:

```js
console.log(TimeConvert(126));

function TimeConvert(num) { 
if(num<60 && num>10){ 
  return 0+":"+num
} 
if(num<10){ 
  return 0+":"+0+num
}

let object={ 
  12:720, 
  11:660,
  10:600,
  9:540,
  8:480,
  7:420,
  6:360,
  5:300,
  4:240,
  3:180,
  2:120,
  1:60
  } 


let time=0;


for (let key in object){ 
  while(num>=object[key]){ 
   time += parseInt(key) 
  num-= object[key]
  }
} 

 
  if (num<10) { num = "0"+num;} // add leading 0 and coerce to string if num <10;

return time+":"+num

}
```

Comment: thank you for showing me how I was doing it wrong. Makes much more sense now

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this algorithm

1. Get the number of times that 60 minutes is in the number argument
2. Get the remainder minutes
3. Concatenate both (with padding for the minutes)
4. Return the answer

```js
const getHoursAndMinsString = (num) => {
  if (num <= 0) {
    return `0:00`
  }
  const hours = Math.floor(num / 60)
  const mins = num % 60
  return `${hours}:${mins.toString().padStart(2, "0")}`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `object` lookup is just encoding n=>n*60, but only for a subset of possible values so is arbitrarily limiting the range of values your function can operate on.

Removing that, and using `floor` and `%` to compute the hours and minutes respectively reduces the code down to:

```
function TimeConvert(num) {
    let time = Math.floor(num / 60);
    num = num % 60;
    if (num < 10) { num = "0" + num; } // add leading 0 and coerce to string if num <10;
    return time + ":" + num;
}
```

These calculations can also be done inline if you rather which reduces the code even further:

```
function TimeConvert(num) {
    return Math.floor(num / 60) + ":" + ((num % 60) < 10 ? "0" : "") + (num % 60);
}
```

just watch out for negative values, or anything higher than 1440, which would overflow past 24 hours and you may want to start displaying with days.